# Using Resampling to understand a large table

Tags: count-data, resampling

I have a data set that is very large.

The attributes (columns) are several thousand. Some are sparse others are not. Some are ordinal, others interval, nominal or ratio.

The row size is 10s of millions of rows.

The data set is evolving -- that is the business is not sure which rows should finally end up in the set -- so they are developing their criteria -- what that means is that a record could be in the data today -- not in it tomorrow and back in the next day -- this is a work in progress.

I have access to the data over a limited connection -- Limited as in limited tools I can use, limited computation power, limited time, etc.

My first problem is that I want to be able to estimate for each column:

1. How many records have the field filled in or not (so null or populated)
2. And then try to estimate the field the value of the field.

What I'm thinking of is deriving subsets of the data using re-sampling and then estimating the counts (item "1").

Is there a formula that can help me understand how how many samples I must take and what confidence the counts will have.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are such formulas - it depends on the accuracy with which you want to estimate the proportion filled in and the accuracy you want on the estimated values. In the first, it relates to [margin of error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error) and [binomial confidence intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). In the second case it depends on what you're trying to estimate about it and the characteristics of the thing (what kind of a variable it is). ... ctd

Comment: ... ctd For example, are you trying to estimate an average? You may need an estimate of the standard deviation for that, in which case you might need to have a pilot sample in order to estimate the sample size you need.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for the response. Let's start with case-1